# cf push - how can I update/push selected files (modified files) using CloudFoundry

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Pushing the entire code every time is time consuming and it's not a good practice.

How can I perform incremental push? Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @jimmc comment:

Cloud Foundry clients ([CLI](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/installcf/), [Java Client](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client), etc) automatically do incremental push of application bits. Here's how it works:

When a CF client is given a directory to push, it gets a list of files in the directory and all subdirectories. When a client is given an archive (.jar, .war, .zip) to push, it explodes the archive locally on the client machine. Only the first level of the archive is exploded, any embedded archives (e.g. .jar files in a .war file) are not exploded. It then gets a list of files in the exploded archive.

The client then calculates a SHA for each file and sends the list of files with SHAs to the CF [resource matching API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/221/resource_match/list_all_matching_resources.html). CF will respond with a list of files that it already has (e.g. from a previous push). The client then sends only the files that CF doesn't already have.

Answer (score 1):

push should be capable of sync:

> $ cf p -h 
>       NAME:
>          push - Push a new app or sync changes to an existing app

However By default, cf push recursively pushes the contents of the current working directory.

> Note: If you want to push more than a single file, but not the entire
>   contents of a directory, consider using a .cfignore file to tell cf
>   push what to exclude

**Example .cfignore file contents:**

tmp/ 
log/ 
my_unnecessary_file.txt

When executing your next cf push for deploying the application it will omit the files and directories listed in your .cfignore file.

Regards

Comment: Be sure that you're using a current version of the cf command line tool for sync capabilities so that only modified files are pushed (based on a comparison of sha1 values).

The determination of which files should be pushed is done by a `PUT /v2/resource_match` which you can see if you set `CF_TRACE=true`